# Set & Get Cookies in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using asp.net core 2.0 mvc c#

I have 2 applications within the same domain ie

```
www.mydomain.com/app1 
www.mydomain.com/app2
```

There is a link on the first application app1 which one clicked redirects to my second application app2.

I want to pass an ID from app1 to app2. I have tried querystrings. Though I am successfully able to set that its difficult to maintain/pass those in my app2 when there are redirects going from one page to another.

So I thought of using cookies.
What I want is when the user clicks on link in app1 a cookie is set, I am redirected to app2 and here I want to check the cookie that was set.

I want to check the cookie in the actionfilter as below:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
      //Here I want to check my cookie

    }
}
```

I tried with HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Get but this does not exist.

Any pointers please.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this as below:

App1:
Setting querystring in app1 as below

```
  <a href="http://localhost?id=abc">Click here </a>
```

App2:
Getting the querystring from the context and then creating cookie based on the querystring value. On subsequent request I check the cookie that was created.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
      //this is querystring being passed from app1 to my app2 controller
      string id =  userId = filterContext.ActionArguments["id"].ToString();

        //Creating cookie
       filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Id", is, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
                });

        //Now I can check for this cookie and then proceed or deny acccess
    }
}
```